# migration in mysql gives "invalid table definitions format in file"

Tags: mysql, sql-server, batch-file, mysql-workbench

I used MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE migration wizard to migrate a table from a SQL Server. The migration succeeded!. The migration wizard generate a .cmd file like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
set arg_target_password=xxxx
set arg_worker_count=2

set table_file="%TMP%\wb_tables_to_migrate.txt"
TYPE NUL > "%TMP%\wb_tables_to_migrate.txt"
ECHO [BAD-FAN-SVIL]    [dbo].[DFS_CHECKTYPE]            `BAD-FAN-SVIL` `DFS_CHECKTYPE`                [code],[VERSION]           `code`,`VERSION`            [OPTLOCK], CAST([code] as NVARCHAR(255)) as [code], [VERSION], CAST([DESCRIPTION] as NVARCHAR(255)) as [DESCRIPTION] >> "%TMP%\wb_tables_to_migrate.txt"

cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE

wbcopytables.exe --odbc-source="DSN=xxxXXX;DATABASE=;UID=XX" --target="form@182.178.21.1:3306" --target-password="%arg_target_password%" --table-file="%table_file%" --thread-count=%arg_worker_count%
REM Removes the file with the table definitions
DEL "%TMP%\wb_tables_to_migrate.txt"
```

But when I re-Run this it gives me the error: "invalid table definitions format in file wb_tables_to_migrate.txt"

Comment: Maybe, because the table already exists. Try to drop table before re-run

Comment: I've already dropped it

Comment: @dax90 you shouldn't delete table before run this script (table was generated in migration wizard not in wbcopytable.exe, that is actually only data copy tool), however table should be empty

Comment: @dax90 and one more thing - properly format for `wb_tables_to_migrate.txt` file is:
`source_schema \t source_table \t target_schema \t target_table \t source_pk_columns \t target_pk_columns \t select_expression`

there should be one line with exactly 7 fileds separeted by tab, so make sure that when you edit your script your editor didn't replace tabs with spaces